# Maximum call stack size exceeded angular2

Tags: angular

I am using angular 2, and i've been tryin to consume some REST api (jax rs) but i am getting this error "Maximum call stack size exceeded" when i am calling the getALL method.
This is my service:

```
getAll(): Observable<Artist[]> {
     let artists$ = this.http
     .get(`${this.baseUrl}`, {headers: 
     this.getHeaders()}).map(this.extractData)
     .catch(this.handleError);
     return artists$;
}
private extractData(res:Response) {
  let body = res.json();
  return body || [];
}
private handleError(error:any) {
  let errMsg = (error.message) ? error.message :
    error.status ? `${error.status} - ${error.statusText}` : 'Server error';
  console.error(errMsg);
  return Observable.throw(errMsg);
}
```

this is the Artist interface:

```
export interface Artist {
  id?:number;
  firstname?:string;
  stageName?:string;
  artistPictures?:string;
  interaction?:Interaction[];
  creations?:Creation[];
  createdDate?:Date;
  owner?:User;
}
```

I am guessing the problem is caused by the attribute owner cause artist have one to many relationship with User but i don't know how to resolve this.

Comment: Maybe you calling `getAll()` over and over again. Set a breakpoint in `getAll` to check it.

Comment: thanks for your answer but i am pretty sure i am calling it one time, i am guessing the problem is caused by the attribute owner cause artist have one to many relationship with User but i don't know how to resolve this kind of problem since i am new to angular.

Comment: You're probably trying to serialize a self-referencing structure to JSON string.